# I use magento 2, when submit contact form then issue on mail

Tags: email, magento, contacts, magento2

I use magento 2, when submit contact form then issue on mail, when receive successfully but problem is apostrophe character.

Suppose any Customer write comment like:  **Can't able to login** then in mail

display like: **Can &#039 ; t able to login**

I use 4-5 latest version all version this common issue,
Please help to resolve if you know

Comment: change contact email template type to html from text

Answer (score 0):

Go to this path "/vendor/magento/module-contact/view/adminhtml/email" and open "submitted_form.html" and replace  19th line code with the below-mentioned code

```
{{trans "Comment: %comment" comment=$data.comment|raw}}
```

Comment: Thanks For great help. Its perfect Work

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the comment of Abhinav Kumar Singh, there's another way for those who are working with copies of the default e-mail templates in admin backend: MARKETING > COMMUNICATIONS > E-MAIL TEMPLATES.

No need to override original Magento files.

After you have imported the Contact-Form Template, you will find the same syntax in the **Template Content** field. Just add the "|raw" tag there.

```
{{trans "Comment: %comment" comment=$data.comment|raw}}
```

or

```
{{var data.comment|raw}}
```